# Supress Java exeption if I know an exeption won't be thrown

Tags: java, try-catch, error-suppression

Is it possible to supress an exeption in a Java code? Suppose I'm trying to do something as basic as this:

```java
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2021-01-01")
```

The `.parse()` method throws an exeption in case the string is in an incorrect format, so a try-catch block is necessary:

```java
try {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2021-01-01")
} catch (ParseExeption e) {
    //Nothing to do here
}
```

However, I know for a fact that an exeption won't be thrown. Is there a way to avoid the use of the try-catch block?

Comment: `parse()` does _not_ throw a _generic_ `Exception`. catch whatever it throws and work on that, _exactly_.

Comment: @Eugene thanks! I've edited the post. However, there is no use for the catch block as it's impossible for the try to throw an exeption.

Comment: create a wrapper method that catches the exception (as you've shown in your post), and then use that wrapper in place of the java method.

Comment: _currently_ it is impossible. change the code 1/2 a year from now - and have a nasty surprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You can't hide this exception.

Since `DateFormat.parse` has `throws ParseException`, you need to catch in your code or add `throws ParseException` state for your method.

The only exceptions you don't need to catch or add `throws` statement to make your program compile are exceptions that inherit `RuntimeException`.

In your case `ParseException` doesn't inherit `RuntimeException`, so you need to catch it or use `throws` keyword.

### Sneaky throws approach

Actually, you can fool Java compiler and sneaky throw checked exception.

This can be achieved by the next method

```java
public static <E extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(Throwable e) throws E {
    throw (E) e;
}
```

And then you can wrap an exception with this method

```
try {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2021-01-01")
} catch (ParseExeption e) {
    sneakyThrow(e);
}
```

As you can see, it **do require** `try/catch` block, but you can use [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) library and it will do all the work for you with annotation `@SneakyThrows`.

```java
@SneakyThrows
public void myMethod() {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2021-01-01");
}
```

Code above will compile, but there is a requirement to use external library.

Comment: ever heard about "sneaky throws"?

Comment: Yes, I have heard about it. But in this case it will require to use `try/catch` block and then sneaky throw an exception, or use Lombok, which is not pure java :) But anyway I will extend my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hard-code a `Date` for January 1st, 2021, do it without using `SimpleDateFormat`, then you won't have to mess with exceptions.

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(2021, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

In Java 8+, use the new Java Time API:

```java
Date date = Date.from(LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1)
                               .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                               .toInstant());
```

```java
Date date = Date.from(LocalDate.parse("2021-01-01")
                               .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                               .toInstant());
```

```java
Date date = Date.from(Year.of(2021).atDay(1)
                          .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                          .toInstant());
```

```java
Date date = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                   .toInstant());
```

If you insist on using `SimpleDateFormat`, make an assertion that it cannot happen.

```java
Date date;
try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2021-01-01");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new AssertionError("Cannot happen: " + e, e);
}
```